# What is the smallest $n$ such that the condition holds?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest $n$ such that for all $a,b$ with $12 \mid a+b$, it is the case that if $n\mid ab$, then $12 \mid a$ and $12 \mid b$?

I think I see how it works if $n = 144$, but I don't know how to prove that it is the smallest (or that there is another value of $n$ which is).

Comment: This question seems a bit ill-posed to me. Given that you feel that $n = 144$ is the 'right' answer,  I think what you want to be asking is "what is the smallest $n$ such that for **all** $a,b$ with $12 \mid a+b$, it is the case that if $n \mid ab$, then $12 \mid a$ and $12 \mid b$?". That is different from asking (as you have) "given **some** $a,b$ such that $12 \mid a + b$, what is the smallest $n$ such that if $n \mid ab$, then $12 \mid a$ and $12 \mid b$"; which would of course depend on $a$ and $b$. E.g., if $a=2, b=10$, then $n=3$ does the job in that case (while $n = 144$ does not).

Comment: @ChasBrown Ah yes, I completely agree. I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. Apparently, $n$ is divisible by 2 and 3, otherwise it couldn't enforce divisibility by 12. Now, the product $ab$ is divisible by 3, which means that at least one of the numbers $a$ and $b$ is divisible by 3, and so is their sum, hence so is the other number. By similar reasoning, both are divisible by 2. So $a=6x,\;b=6y$. Now the question changes to: given that $x+y$ is even, what is the condition on $n$, such that ${n\over36}\mid xy$, that would make both $x$ and $y$ even? The answer is obvious: the product must be even as well, so $n=72$ will suffice.

Answer (score -1):

If I get you right, we have to find $n,a,b$ so that the conditions

- $12 \mid a+b $
- $n \mid ab $
- $12 \mid a $
- $12 \mid b $

hold true.

Well, if you are searching for the smallest possible values, than you might be able to simply check the first numbers with a simple, however inefficient, computer program. This is a Python example:

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.product(range(1,100),range(1,100),range(1,100)):
    n,a,b = i
    if ((a + b) % 12 == 0) and ((a * b) % n == 0):
        if (a % 12 == 0) and (b % 12 == 0):
            print n,a,b
```

The results are:

- 1 12 12
- 1 12 24
- 1 12 36
- 1 12 48
- 1 12 60
- 1 12 72
- ...

Comment: That's _almost_ right, but we need the smallest $n$ such that $12|a,b$ holds for ***any*** $a,b$ for which the first two conditions hold, to which the brute force search, however efficient, is of no help.

Comment: Oh indeed, let me fix this